# Pandas groupby dictionary

Tags: list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, pandas-groupby

New to pandas, sorry if the solution is quite obvious.

I have a dataframe (see below) with different movie scenes and the environment for that movie scene

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'movie' : 'movie_X', 'scene' : '1', 'environment' : 'home'}, 
        {'movie' : 'movie_X', 'scene' : '2', 'environment' : 'car'}, 
        {'movie' : 'movie_X', 'scene' : '3', 'environment' : 'home'}, 
        {'movie' : 'movie_Y', 'scene' : '1', 'environment' : 'home'}, 
        {'movie' : 'movie_Y', 'scene' : '2', 'environment' : 'office'}, 
        {'movie' : 'movie_Z', 'scene' : '1', 'environment' : 'boat'}, 
        {'movie' : 'movie_Z', 'scene' : '2', 'environment' : 'beach'}, 
        {'movie' : 'movie_Z', 'scene' : '3', 'environment' : 'home' }]
myDF = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In this case, the the movies have multiple genres to which they belong to. I have a dictionary (below) describing for each movie which genres it belongs to

```
genreDict = {'movie_X' : ['romance', 'action'],
           'movie_Y' : ['comedy', 'romance', 'action'],
           'movie_Z' : ['horror', 'thriller', 'romance']}
```

I wanted to group myDF by this dictionary, specifically be able to tell the number of times a specific environment turned up in a particular genre (for example, in the genre horror, 'boat' was counted once, 'beach' was counted once, and 'home' was counted once). What would be the best and most efficient way of going about this? I have tried mapping the dictionary to the dataframe and then grouping by the list:

```
myDF['genres'] = myDF['movie'].map(genreDict)
```

Which returns:

```
   movie    scene    environment               genres
0  movie_X     1        home            [romance, action]
1  movie_X     2         car            [romance, action]
2  movie_X     3        home            [romance, action]
3  movie_Y     1        home    [comedy, romance, action]
4  movie_Y     2      office    [comedy, romance, action]
5  movie_Z     1        boat  [horror, thriller, romance]
6  movie_Z     2       beach  [horror, thriller, romance]
7  movie_Z     3        home  [horror, thriller, romance]
```

However, I got an error saying the list was unhashable. Hopefully you all can help :)

Comment: can you post your desired data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If larger dataframe faster is use `numpy` for repeat rows by `lists` with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html),  [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) and [`Index.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.values.html):

```
#get length of lists in column genres
l = myDF['genres'].str.len()
#convert column to numpy array
vals = myDF['genres'].values
#repeat index by lenghts
idx = np.repeat(myDF.index, l)
#expand rows by duplicated index values 
myDF = myDF.loc[idx]
#flattening lists column
myDF['genres'] = np.concatenate(vals)
#default monotonic index (0,1,2...)
myDF = myDF.reset_index(drop=True)
print (myDF)
   environment    movie scene    genres
0         home  movie_X     1   romance
1         home  movie_X     1    action
2          car  movie_X     2   romance
3          car  movie_X     2    action
4         home  movie_X     3   romance
5         home  movie_X     3    action
6         home  movie_Y     1    comedy
7         home  movie_Y     1   romance
8         home  movie_Y     1    action
9       office  movie_Y     2    comedy
10      office  movie_Y     2   romance
11      office  movie_Y     2    action
12        boat  movie_Z     1    horror
13        boat  movie_Z     1  thriller
14        boat  movie_Z     1   romance
15       beach  movie_Z     2    horror
16       beach  movie_Z     2  thriller
17       beach  movie_Z     2   romance
18        home  movie_Z     3    horror
19        home  movie_Z     3  thriller
20        home  movie_Z     3   romance
```

Then use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['genres','environment']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
      genres environment  count
0     action         car      1
1     action        home      3
2     action      office      1
3     comedy        home      1
4     comedy      office      1
5     horror       beach      1
6     horror        boat      1
7     horror        home      1
8    romance       beach      1
9    romance        boat      1
10   romance         car      1
11   romance        home      4
12   romance      office      1
13  thriller       beach      1
14  thriller        boat      1
15  thriller        home      1
```

Answer (score 3):

Non scalar objects cause problems in pandas generally. In addition to that, you need to tidy up your data so that your next steps are easier (main operations on tabular structures are generally defined on tidy data sets). You need a data set where you don't list all the genres in a row, but instead each genre has its own row.

Here's one of the possible ways to achieve that:

```
genre_df = pd.DataFrame(myDF['movie'].map(genreDict).tolist())

df = myDF.join(genre_df.stack().rename('genre').reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
df
Out: 
  environment    movie scene     genre
0        home  movie_X     1   romance
0        home  movie_X     1    action
1         car  movie_X     2   romance
1         car  movie_X     2    action
2        home  movie_X     3   romance
2        home  movie_X     3    action
3        home  movie_Y     1    comedy
3        home  movie_Y     1   romance
3        home  movie_Y     1    action
4      office  movie_Y     2    comedy
4      office  movie_Y     2   romance
4      office  movie_Y     2    action
5        boat  movie_Z     1    horror
5        boat  movie_Z     1  thriller
5        boat  movie_Z     1   romance
6       beach  movie_Z     2    horror
6       beach  movie_Z     2  thriller
6       beach  movie_Z     2   romance
7        home  movie_Z     3    horror
7        home  movie_Z     3  thriller
7        home  movie_Z     3   romance
```

Once you have a structure like this, it is much easier to group or cross tabulate your data:

```
df.groupby('genre').size()
Out: 
genre
action      5
comedy      2
horror      3
romance     8
thriller    3
dtype: int64

pd.crosstab(df['genre'], df['environment'])
Out: 
environment  beach  boat  car  home  office
genre                                      
action           0     0    1     3       1
comedy           0     0    0     1       1
horror           1     1    0     1       0
romance          1     1    1     4       1
thriller         1     1    0     1       0
```

Here's a great read by Hadley Wickham: [Tidy Data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html).